# sort function is giving unexpected results in c++

Tags: c++, sorting

I have structure data as:

```
typedef struct 
{
    int num,index;
} data;
```

and my sort function as:

```
bool comp(const data &i , const data &j)
{
    return (i.num < j.num);
}
```

and here is my main function:

```
int t,n,p,tcase,i,j;
vector<data> a;
vector<int > b ;

cin >> n;

a.resize(n);
b.resize(n);

j=0;

for(i=0 ; i<2*n ; i++)
{
    if(i%2)
    {
        b.emplace_back();
        cin >> b[j];
        j++;
    }
    else
    {
        a.emplace_back();
        cin >> a[j].num;
        a[j].index = j;
    }
}

for(i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
{
    cout << a[i].num << endl;
}

cout << endl;

sort(a.begin() , a.end() , comp);

for(i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
{

    cout << a[i].num << endl;
}

a.erase(a.begin() , a.end());
b.erase(b.begin() , b.end());       
tcase++;
```

So when I run my program with following input:

```
4 15 25 30 35 45 50 10 20
```

then my expected answer should be:

```
10 15 30 45
```

But my program is giving:

```
0 0 0 0
```

Where am I doing wrong ?

Comment: For one, drop the "typedef struct {...} foo;", that's a C-ism that is completely unnecessary in C++. Then, what's the content of the array before sorting?

Comment: What do you expect `a.emplace_back();` to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just comment these lines.

```
a.emplace_back();
```

and

```
b.emplace_back();
```

And you are good to go.

And yes emplace_back appends the new element at the end of container. and you don't need that here.
Link: http://ideone.com/o92WE6

Comment: problem was with my basics as i am new to C++ STL. Thanx for the help.

Answer (score -1):

You can declare the comparison function as a class and overload () operator on it to give an easy implementation

```
class Compare
    {
    public:
    bool operator()(f_coord a,f_coord b)
    {
        return(a.val>b.val);
    }
    };
```